# How do I print LINQ query in Visual Basic?

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq

```
Dim query = From row In WorkingDataSet.Tables("myTable").AsEnumerable()
                            Group By InvoiceNumber = row.Field(Of String)("InvoiceNumber") Into InvoiceSum = Sum(row.Field(Of Decimal)("InvoicePaymentAmount"))
                            Select InvoiceNumber, InvoiceSum
```

I want to display InvoiceNumber and InvoiceSum but I dont know how to loop through my query to display them in a format like this.

```
InvoiceNumber: 154145, InvoiceSum, $13434.12

InvoiceNumber: 154145, InvoiceSum, $13434.12

InvoiceNumber: 154145, InvoiceSum, $13434.12

InvoiceNumber: 154145, InvoiceSum, $13434.12

InvoiceNumber: 154145, InvoiceSum, $13434.12

InvoiceNumber: 154145, InvoiceSum, $13434.12

InvoiceNumber: 154145, InvoiceSum, $13434.12
```

Comment: `For Each row In query ...`

Comment: @Heinzi it says row is not declared.

Comment: If the query result belongs to the same, non-anonymous class, you normally print it by overriding the `ToString()` method of the class. Otherwise, you should go through the item one by one by loop and print them.

Comment: @Heinzi I turned it on and it compiled, is there a way to do this explicitly typed?

Comment: @codemonkeyliketab: Yes, if you replace `Select InvoiceNumber, InvoiceSum` with an explicit class (e.g. `Select New MyClass(InvoiceNumber, InvoiceSum)`) instead of an implicit one. If you use an implicit class, you need to use implicit typing. But you need implicit typing for `Dim query = ...` anyway right? (I mean, you do have Option Strict On, right? If you don't, you effectively don't use typing anyway and could just say `For Each row as Object In query`. But **please don't do that**.)

Comment: Heinzi´s answer + `String.Format("InvoiceNumber: {0}, InvoiceSum: ${1:N}", row.InvoiceNumber, row.InvoiceSum)`

Comment: @AlexB.: Or rather `$"Invoice: {row.InvoiceNumber}, InvoiceSum: {row.InvoiceSum:N}"`. Let's not teach outdated syntax. ;-)

Comment: @Heinzi since the question owner did not tell us which .net version he is using I stayed with the old fashioned way. But yes, I like the new format option too :)

Comment: @Heinzi Can you explain what the dollar sign infront of a string does? I am using .net 4.0 and have never see that syntax.

Comment: @codemonkeyliketab: [MSDN: Interpolated Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

If the query result belongs to the same, non-anonymous `class`, you normally print it by overriding the `ToString()` method of the `class`. Otherwise, you should go through the item one by one by loop and print them.

```
For Each q In query
    Console.WriteLine("InvoiceNumber: " + q.InvoiceNumber + ", InvoiceSum, $" + q.InvoiceSum.ToString("F2"))
Next
```

One important concept (which may be misunderstood here) is that `LINQ` is primarily designed for *querying*, not for *action* or *assignment*. When you want to *print* something out (it is an *action*), you should use `For Each` on each element rather than using `LINQ`

Comment: I´d prefer using format string and not concatenating them with `+` ;)

Comment: @AlexB. Ah yes, `Console.WriteLine("InvoiceNumber: {0}, InvoiceSum, ${1}: {1:F2}", q.InvoiceNumber, q.InvoiceSum)` is certainly another option when using `Console.WriteLine()` :)